# Is there any significant downside to just always using transactions in JDBI?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, transactions, jdbi

For tables that will never get too large, is there any downside to just using `JdbiExecutor::executeInTransaction` instead of `JdbiExecutor::execute`?

I'm trying to simplify a very large and complex piece of code so that new developers can onboard more quickly. If there isn't a significant difference in performance (which, even then, it would be premature optimization to address it here) then I'd like write a utility that just always uses `JdbiExecutor::executeInTransaction`.

Comment: I do understand transactions / atomicity / rollbacks, btw. Here I'm asking whether _not_ having to transaction really "saves" that much for a non-performance-intensive process, so that if not, I can simplify code to always using transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL server operates in autocommit mode, so using explicit transactions will not only cause `COMMIT` statements to be sent to the database, but also `BEGIN` statements that start an explicit transaction.

That means you could have up to 2 extra client-server round trips per transaction.

Using explicit transactions only if you need to bundle multiple statements into a transaction might improve your performance.

I would run a simple benchmark to see if the impact is noticeable; if not, go ahead and simplify your code.

Comment: If the two extra round-trips between app and database is even 1% as costly as the query itself, then you have something wrong with your network.

Comment: @BillKarwin Not true. If your queries are short (OLTP) network latency can easily be the dominant cost factor.